React Query: clear data before refetch
Really simple thing, if a URL parameter changes, previous data is no longer valid and should be cleared. However, when calling refetch from useEffect, useQuery doesn't do that.
Is there some parameter I should pass or something else?

If the parameters to useQuery changes you shouldn't need to call refetch at all. Batching/fetching/caching is normally handled automatically.

Maybe you are getting the URL parameters without passing them through useQuery?

@super Thank you! That's exactly what was going on. I've included URL parameter value as queryKey and now it works like you described.

You can achieved this by invalidating the query. From the official docs:

Query Invalidation
Mutation Invalidation

